# Checking if a particular bit is set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to check if the 2nd bit from LSB is set.
I use the below function to do this.
If it was the 1st bit I could simple return `(uintptr_t) p & 1`.
Since I'm checking if the second bit is set, I'm doing one more operation `==`.
Is there a clever way with which this can be achieved using just one instruction?

```
static inline bool is2ndBitSet(void* p)
{
    return ((uintptr_t) p & 2) == 2;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just tried the suggestions in the comments and yes, I'm doing redundant comparison

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
static inline bool is2ndBitSet(void* p)
{
    return ((uintptr_t) p & 2);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long* ptr = (unsigned long*) 0x4;
    unsigned long* ptr1 = (unsigned long*) 0x3;
    if(is2ndBitSet(ptr))
    {
        printf("bit is set\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("bit is not set\n");
    }
    if(is2ndBitSet(ptr1))
    {
        printf("bit is set\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("bit is not set\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
bit is not set
bit is set
```

Comment: `p & 2`? what am I missing?

Comment: return `int` and have zero mean false, and non-zero mean truth-y. Then `p & 2` is perfectly valid.

Comment: `p&2` will return `2` and not `1`. I can return `int` but I wanted to keep it simple and hence `bool`.

Comment: A clever compiler, if able, will compile your code, _as is_, into 1 instruction.  Lines-of-code do not necessarily equal instruction count.

Comment: anything different from 0 will be false. A boot is actually an int or char depending on the compiler, but the result is the same, so no need to compare

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Ahh. That makes sense. I just tried that and you are right. I'm doing redundant comparison

Answer (score 0):

- Unless you really need to normalize your result, there's no need to use bool and normalize. I think that is the only way to go. (until the compiler gets it.) C and C++ accept only 0 as false, all else is true.

  - If you stay with bool and omit normalizing yourself, the compiler will silently do it.
- You seem to think you know what the compiker will output, though you don't. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil, and this is it for sure.

Comment: `You seem to think you know what the compiker will output, though you don't`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Simply said, concentrate on the proper algorithms and laying out your data the right way, using the right types. Trust the compiler to get such a detail as you asked about right, unless you get specific evidence it does not.

Comment: I think Deduplicator is questioning your use of pointers when you aren't doing things that one would normally use a pointer for. Or at least I am.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Fair enough.

Comment: The point is that with a good compiler, which most are these days, it will optimize your code far, far better than you can unless you are an assembly language guru. In most cases, like 999 out of 1000, it's better to write highly readable code than to worry about whether you have made things as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

0 stands for **FALSE** 
Anything else stands for **TRUE**

doing just `if (p & 2)` or `if (p & 0x2)` should be just fine.

p.s

I just typed down the same thing with a hex value cause hex values from 0 to F are used to represent set/unset bits in nibbles (4 bits in a row) it makes things easier to follow if you're doing bit operations a lot.

Comment: using `if` is another way of doing what I did.

Comment: The `if` part was just for clarity. Have you tried compiling and testing without the `== 2` part and see what happens?

Comment: I just did, and it works just fine. `(uintptr_t)p & 2`